# URL Duplicating in CodeIgniter Like http://localhost/CI/login/login/login

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, codeigniter-url, codeigniter-routing

Am working on a codeigniter application.
I have a login.php with the following code

```
public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('login');
    }
    public function login()
    {
        $username=$this->input->post('username');
        $password=$this->input->post('password');
        $data=array(
            'username'=>'$username',
            'password'=>'$password'
        );
        if(1){
            redirect($this->config->base_url().'admin');
        }
        else{
            redirect($this->config->base_url().'login');
        }
    }
```

I have declared login as the default_controller.

I have view login.php which has a login form and submit action to login/login. when I click on submit button.

```
url-at-the-address-bar  expected-url  redirected-url
[root]                  login/login   login/login
login/login             login/login   login/login/login
login/login/login       login/login   login/login/login/login
```

and so on. The url keeps adding up.
Tried htaccess. htaccess has effects on this issue. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the suggestion by Simo, but it did not work. I finally found the answer by changing the form action to:

```
<form action="http://localhost/CI/login/login" method="post">
```

Comment: Thank you Harish N Gowda finally found the solution.

Comment: You are using a static uri, and this is a bad practice, take a look at form_helper, there is a lot of useful functions in it, or you can use <form action="<?php echo base_url('login/login') ?>" method="post">

Answer (score 0):

dont use base_url() when redirecting to other contollers, you should change this :

```
if(1){
  redirect($this->config->base_url().'admin');
}
else{
  redirect($this->config->base_url().'login');
}
```

to this :

```
$is_logged = false; // To replace with login statement.

if($is_logged)
  redirect('admin');
else
  redirect('login');
```